# Story in a 70's anthology in which earth is a teenager's school project

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story involved a man and a woman and I believe the man was a messiah like creature or perfect being and the man and woman are interrupted during sex by a god.  Also it seems the story involved Earth being a teen-ager's schoool project that gets destroyed by an older sibling.  My memory here is far from perfect.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like several stories.,.

Comment: Sounds like a ripoff of Unpleasant Profession of Jonathan Hoag.